# Team needs vs Team need

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I want to inform other that one of the team require additional time to close a task. which one is appropriate

```
Team needs more time
```

or

```
Team need more time
```

Comment: The team needs more time.  Several members of the team need more time.  All the teams need more time.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at our sister site, English Language Learners, https://english.stackexchange.com/.  It may be a better fit for your questions